# getting a specific adjacent element in jquery

Tags: jquery

if I have the following table:

```
<tr class="alternate">
    <td>{$order.titel}</td>
    <td>{$order.auteur}</td>
    <td>&euro;{$order.prijs}</td>
    <td>{$order.aantal}</td>
    <td>&euro; {$order.aantal*$order.prijs}</td>
<tr>
```

and inside jquery I currently have the 4th td selected, how can i get the data from within the first td, keeping in mind that I start looking from the 4th td (eg. the 4th td is 'this')?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var first = $(this).siblings().first();
```

Or, for one of the other elements:

```
var second = $(this).siblings().eq(1);
```

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: No, eq is 1-based

Comment: @Harmen, [really](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)? Documentation says it's zero-based.

Comment: Yes, it's zero-based.  Hence `second = ` :-)

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: You're right, I'm confused with `nth-child()` which is 1-based

Comment: @lonesomeday, you're right, I was blinded by the question mentioning the first `<td>` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)** method which returns the preceding sibling.

```
var first = $(this).prev().prev().prev();
```